# Using CSS transitions with full-page div overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Currently, I have a (hopefully-not-**too**-hackish-but-certainly-mildly-so; see below) page in which a 'see more' link "uncovers" a full-page `div` overlay:

https://jsfiddle.net/6241cphL/3/

I would like to incorporate some sort of [CSS transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) so that the overlay(s) appear/disappear a bit more...gracefully. Is there a way to do this?

Before posting here, I'd tried a number of things:

- I tried adding a `.hidden` and/or `.visible` class which I applied/unapplied to `#container` and/or `#inner` via Javascript (stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21512040)).
- I also tried adapting [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/toggle-visibility-when-hiding-elements/) `fade-in`/`fade-out` model + [this](http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337) `li`-menu example as well, all to no avail.

**Note:** As mentioned above, this thing is almost-assuredly-hackish, at least mildly so. For my needs, the general structure/functionality used here is perfectly fine, and while I *do* welcome general constructive feedback (everyone's goal is to get better, I think), I would prefer if such feedback **also** came with suggestions on how to achieve the result I'm seeking within the framework I've already implemented. :)

Comment: (offtpic) Don't use `>>>` to create arrows-ish. You know what are those used for in HTML. Use the escaped representation instead `&gt;&gt;&gt;`

Comment: You're absolutely right, @RokoC.Buljan: I was being lazy. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Toggle the overlay class:

```js
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

function toggleOverlay() {
  overlay.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left:0; top:0; bottom:0; right:0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
  transition: 0.5s;
  
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#overlay.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleOverlay()">Show overlay</button>

<div id="overlay">
  <button onclick="toggleOverlay()">Close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting inline styles, add/remove a class name (like `opened`)
You can then use CSS transitions/animations.
Use [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event and similar if you want to add another class name at the end of the transition (i.e. `closed`) which would be useful to set some properties like `display: none`.

Comment: There's no need to `transitionend` and `display: none`. All OP needs if to *gracefully* (fade perhaps)  in/out the overlays. (All doable with `visibility`, `transition` and `opacity`... so CSS-alone)

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Giacomo, and forgive me for asking but: Could you possibly show me what you mean in a Fiddle and/or expanded answer? I'm a hobbyist designer at best, and I'm not 100% sure how to combine the words you're saying with what the provided link (which I appreciate very much!) demonstrates.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: I assumed it was doable using CSS-alone as well. Do you have any specific suggestions I may apply to my example?

Comment: Forgive me, @GiacomoCosimato, but the Fiddle you linked doesn't seem to be any different than the one I originally linked to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways. Another option

```js
var right_link = document.getElementById('right_link');
var inn = document.getElementById('inner');
var link = document.getElementById('link');

function makeVisible() {
  if (inn.classList.contains('active')) {
    inn.classList.remove('active');
  } else {
    inn.classList.add('active');
  }
}
right_link.addEventListener('click', makeVisible)
```

```css
#inner {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all .3s;
}

#inner.active {
  background-color: #888888;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all .3s;
}
```

```html
<span id="right_link">Click me</span>
<div id="inner">
</div>
```